# Show that a function can not be harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, harmonic-functions

> A function $u$ is twice continuously differentiable in $D(0,2)$. It has the property: $u(e^{i\theta})=cos(\theta)$ and $u(0)=1$
>   Show that $u$ can not be harmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that the average of $u$ along the unit circle is 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\theta)d\theta=0$$
 which is less than $1=u(0)$. On the other hand, harmonic functions satisfy the [mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property).

Comment: Will showing that the mean value property fails be enough if we use a sufficiently small circle like $D(0,1)$ or $e^{i\theta}$? Or would assuming that the function is harmonic be wrong?

Comment: Harmonic functions satisfy the mean value property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property

Comment: So trying to prove this using this property would be wrong?

Comment: No, it means that $u$ does not satisfy the mean value property which implies that $u$ is not harmonic in $D(0,2)$.

Comment: Is it a valid way to show that $u$ is not harmonic?

Comment: @Newphonewhothis What do you have in mind?

Comment: What I tried to far is to do from $0$ to $2\pi$ $u(0)=\frac {1}{2\pi} \int u(0+e^{i\theta}) \,d\theta$ and i get that that is equal to 0 and not 1.

Comment: Fine. So what may we conclude about the function $u$?

Comment: That it is not harmonic? I am not sure if this is a viable way of showing it

Comment: Yes, it is not harmonic. Why are you doubtful?

Comment: The reasoning seemed a tad too simple. I thought there must be something that I missed. I was doubtful about assuming that $u$ is harmonic to begin with

Comment: This is a contradiction proof. Assume that $u$ is harmonic, show that it has not the mean value property. Contradiction. So $u$ can't be harmonic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K=\{z \in \mathbb C:|z| \le 1\}$. Suppose that $u$ is harmonic. Then

$\max u(K)= \max u( \partial K)= \max \{ cos t : t \in [0,2 \pi]\}=1$

and, since $u(0)=1$, the function $u$ has a maximum in $K^o$. By the Maximum - principle, $u$ is constant on $K$, but this is a contradiction to $ u(e^{i\theta})=cos(\theta)$.

Comment: By $K^o$ you mean the interior of $K$, correct?

Comment: Also, why is it okay to consider the closed unit disc instead of $D(0,2)$?

Comment: Yes, $K^o$ is the interior of $K$. To get a contradiction it is enough to consider $K$.